# Angular ngIf doesn't take into account async variable

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I'm implementing an Angular application based upon the google drive API.

My configuration is the following :

- "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
- "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
- "@angular/material": "^13.0.1",
- "@types/gapi": "^0.0.41",
- "rxjs": "~7.4.0"

In short, there is a classical architecture with a service in charge of retrieving information from google API and a component in charge of displaying information.

Here are the code for the two elements :

### First the service

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

declare const gapi: any;

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    public auth2: any;

    public isSignIn: boolean;

    private isSignInChange: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public isSignInObs: Observable<boolean> = this.isSignInChange.asObservable();

    constructor() {
        //Init various variables
        this.isSignIn = false;
        this.isSignInChange.next(false);
        //Load the google api for future OAUTH load
        gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {this.googleInitClient(); });
    }

    private googleInitClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
            ...
        }).then( (res: any) => {
            // Listen for sign-in state changes.
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen( (res: boolean) => {this.updateSigninStatus(res)} );
            // Handle the initial sign-in state.
            this.updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        }, (error: any) => {
            console.warn(error);
        });
    }

    public updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn: boolean) {
       this.isSignIn = isSignedIn;
        this.isSignInChange.next(isSignedIn);
    }

    public signIn() {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }
}
```

### The component script

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public signIn() {
    this.userService.signIn();
  }

  public signOut() {
    this.userService.signOut();
  }
}
```

### The component template

```
<button *ngIf="userService.isSignInObs | async; else elseBlock" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="my"><mat-icon>avatar</mat-icon></button>
<mat-menu #my="matMenu" yPosition="above" [overlapTrigger]="false">
  <button mat-menu-item disabled><mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon> {{currentUser?.nom}}</button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled><mat-icon>email</mat-icon> {{currentUser?.mail}}</button>
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/configuration"><mat-icon>settings</mat-icon> Configuration</button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="signOut()"><mat-icon>logout</mat-icon> Déconnexion</button>
</mat-menu>
<ng-template #elseBlock><a mat-button (click)="signIn()" title="Se connecter"><mat-icon>login</mat-icon></a></ng-template>
```

### The problem

I have a common problem (many threads on the subject) but I can't get it to work properly. In fact, as soon as I finish loading the google drive API (`this.isSignInChange.next(isSignedIn);`), I should have the condition in my ngIf (`userService.isSignInObs | async`) changed to `true`and my template should update. But whatever the implementing solution (I've try a lot of solution), the template does'tn change until I click some where in the view.

The only solution that I manage is to use ChangeDetectorRef but :

- I don't understand why I need to use it while it should work without it (ex: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/)
- If, despite everything, I decide to use it, it disturbs the functioning of the `<mat-expansion-panel>` material component`

Can you help me to find what's wrong with my code !?
Yhanks in advance

Comment: To complete my question, I've finally succeed to fix the problem with `<mat-expansion-panel>`. That means I can use `ChangeDetectorRef ` but I don't like the idea... and appreciate any further help !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a copy error, or it's the problem, but you've missed inject the service in your 'component script' constructor:

```
constructor(
   public userService: UserService 
) {}
```

Once you inject the service, you could try something like this (I guess you really wanted to show the *mat-menu* only if the user is signned, so I put it inside the *ng-container*. If it's not, you can put the whole 'mat-menu block' below, at the end of the code (under the code of 'ng-template #elseBlock')):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="userService.isSignInObs | async as isSignIn; else elseBlock">
   <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="my"><mat-icon>avatar</mat-icon></button>

<mat-menu #my="matMenu" yPosition="above" [overlapTrigger]="false">
      <button mat-menu-item disabled><mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>{{currentUser?.nom}}</button>
      <button mat-menu-item disabled><mat-icon>email</mat-icon>{{currentUser?.mail}}</button>
     <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/configuration"><mat-icon>settings</mat-icon> Configuration</button>
     <button mat-menu-item (click)="signOut()"><mat-icon>logout</mat-icon> Déconnexion</button>
</mat-menu>

</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseBlock><a mat-button (click)="signIn()" title="Se connecter"><mat-icon>login</mat-icon></a></ng-template>
```

UPDATE: If it doesn't work, could you just try to change this line in your 'UserService':

```
private isSignInChange: BehaviorSubject<boolean|null> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
```

I'm afraid the problem is about the 'falsy' value of isSignInObs (not just 'false', but *null*, *undefined*,...).
Perhaps reversing the logic?, something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!userService.isSignInObs | async as isSignIn; else elseBlock">
   <a mat-button (click)="signIn()" title="Se connecter"><mat-icon>login</mat-icon></a>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #elseBlock>

    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="my"><mat-icon>avatar</mat-icon></button>

    <mat-menu #my="matMenu" yPosition="above" [overlapTrigger]="false">
       <button mat-menu-item disabled><mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>{{currentUser?.nom}}</button>
       <button mat-menu-item disabled><mat-icon>email</mat-icon>{{currentUser?.mail}}</button>
       <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/configuration"><mat-icon>settings</mat-icon> Configuration</button>
       <button mat-menu-item (click)="signOut()"><mat-icon>logout</mat-icon> Déconnexion</button>
    </mat-menu>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: `userService` cannot be private if you want to use it in the template

Comment: Good point!, I'll edit in my answer, thxs!

Comment: Thanks, but the user Service was already injected. I try to add the `as isSignIn` but the problem persists.

Comment: Please, read my update. I hope it works.

Comment: No it's not changing anything.

Comment: I tryed to understand the reason why I have to use ChangeDetectorRef and I may have an idea. 

In fact as indicated I use the Google API to access the Google drive. The Google API is executed in a classical Javascript library which outside Angular. 

Consequently all asynchronous call are realised outside Angular and for all the Google API calls I have to use ChangeDetectorRef.

Can you confirm this ?

Comment: No, sorry, I couldn't tell you anything about it.. I'm very focused on Angular, rather than classical JS, so I don't know the implications of using "externals" ways.